# How do I get a sound/alert to play every time a new div is appended to a div?

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have a `div` where `div`s are constantly being added. Using inspect element I was able to determine that these newly appended `div`s are identified by the classname `xyz`.

How can I play a sound every time a new `div` is appended?

Comment: I think that would be a javascript function. I dont know how you would do this in css.

Comment: true. unfortunately i dont know much about javascript. is it hard to set up something like this? i may have to contact coders i know

Comment: You need to 1.find the element by queryselector("div.xyz") 2.add an event listener to dom change

Comment: Take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Answer (score 3):

Use a [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to listen for changes to the element and [`Audio`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement/Audio) to play a sound:

```js
let observer = new MutationObserver(callback);

function callback(mutations) {
  new Audio('https://www.myinstants.com/media/sounds/ding-sound-effect_2.mp3').play();
}

observer.observe(document.querySelector('.items'), {
  childList: true
});

/* below is for debugging */

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', ()=>{
  const div = document.createElement("div");
  div.classList.add('xyz');
  document.querySelector('.items').appendChild(div);
})
```

```css
.xyz {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.items{
  display:flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="xyz">

  </div>
</div>

<button>Add</button>
```

Comment: Wow, you're fast. Was writing exactly the same thing :)

Comment: I would only add this option to `observe` method: `attributeFilter: ['class']` in order to narrow to class attribute changes only

Comment: interesting. thanks for the reply. now just need to figure out how to get this set up lol i know absolutely 0 about coding